# Need to copy the contents of a text file to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a text file such that each line consists of one word followed by a comma-separated list of that word's synonyms. So for example, one line would look like this:

```
word, synonym1, synonym2, synonym3
```

so the first word in each line is the key and the rest are its values

Comment: Please show what you did so far.

Comment: All I have is
f = open("file","r")
contents = f.read()

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

```
with open('file_name.txt') as fobj:    
    synonyms = {}
    for line in fobj:
        key, *values = [entry.strip() for entry in line.split(',')]
        synonyms[key] = values
```

produces this dictionary `synonyms`:

```
{'word1': ['synonym11', 'synonym12', 'synonym13'],
 'word2': ['synonym21', 'synonym22', 'synonym23']}
```

for this file content:

```
word1, synonym11, synonym12, synonym13
word2, synonym21, synonym22, synonym23
```

### Explanation

1. Open the file using `with open('file_name.txt') as fobj:` This opens the file with the promise to close it after dedenting.
2. Make a new empty dictionary: `synonyms = {}`.
3. Go through all lines `for line in fobj:`.
4. Split each line at the comma and remove extra white space from each word: `[entry.strip() for entry in line.split(',')].`
5. Use the new `*`-way to unpack an iterable in Python 3 to split key and values `key, *values =`.
6. Add the values to the result `synonyms[key] = values`.

### Addition:

Print word and a random synonym:

```
import random

for word, syns in synonyms.items():
    print(word, random.choice(syns))
```

prints:

```
word1 synonym12
word2 synonym22
```

Comment: Are you sure that OP doesn't want to remove these commas?

Comment: Just noticed that when writing the explanation. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Hey this works just fine. The only problem is that if I iterate through the dictionary and want to print the value of a given key, it prints it out in a list.. I am trying to figure out a way where I can randomly return just 1 value of the list of values for that given key

Comment: So I have
word = input("Search for a word:")
if word in synonyms:
   print(synonyms[word])